# Role of __WORDSIZE in compilation

Tags: c, linux, mingw

Below are the contents of /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs-32.h file:

```
#include <bits/wordsize.h>    
#if __WORDSIZE == 32
# include <gnu/stubs-32.h>
#elif __WORDSIZE == 64
# include <gnu/stubs-64.h>
#else
# error "unexpected value for __WORDSIZE macro"
#endif
```

I am on 64 Bit machine, so the result of

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
printf("Word size : %d\n",__WORDSIZE);
}
```

is

```
Word size : 64
```

So here is the question, what is the role of the system variable __WORDSIZE?
I am developing a 32 bit application( using mingw 32 bit compiler) and since my __WORDSIZE is 64 bit, the file `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs-32.h` ultimately results in including `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs-64.h`. I am confused about this part. What are the consequences of this action? Is this normal and if not how can I forcibly include `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs-32.h`?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: You can use the `-m32` option to make gcc generate code for 32 bit environment: `gcc -m32 file.c`.

Comment: That's great news !! What about the role these files?

Comment: Compiler decides, based on target architecture, what word size to use and includes internal headers accordingly. I don't think you should be inspecting these headers yourself in code to decide anything.

Comment: @BlueMoon : Accidentally stumbled across this one as I got `error: #include nested too deeply`, then had a second thought about it.

Comment: Why are you looking at headers in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu` in association with a mingw32 (cross-)compiler?  Those headers belong to your (linux) platform native compiler, and *under no circumstances* should the mingw32 compiler ever be allowed to see them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a manifest constant, intended for internal use by the compiler implementation *exclusively*; that its name is prefixed by two underscores is a clear indicator that it is not intended for use in user space.

Comment: My compilation command was `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.6 -o clientinfo.exe clientinfo.c \`mysql_config --libs --cflags\`` and I got this error `usr/local/mysql/include/my_global.h:357:20: fatal error: alloca.h: No such file or directory` So I was forced to include `/usr/include` which contained this file. But then I got `fatal error: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory` , so I was forced to include `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Comment: Or am I not supposed to include these directories and instead find the mingw alternative for every such instances.?

Comment: @sjsam: You must ***never*** add the linux headers include path, when you compile with a MinGW (or indeed, with any other) cross-compiler; therein lies nothing but grief. You must ***always*** seek an alternative which is compatible with the cross-compiler's target platform. Sometimes, that means that you must implement it yourself, (which means you must put in some porting effort). In the case of `alloca()`, however, this is declared in `malloc.h`, and there is no need for `alloca.h`.