# What hardware specific defines does the c89 standard require the implementation to provide?

Tags: c, standards, c89

Does the c(89) standard specify certain hardware properties that must be defined by the implementation? For example on my Linux system there is a define for `__WORDSIZE` (defined as 64) - can I expect `__WORDSIZE` to be defined on every system complying with c(89)? Are there other hardware specific values that the c standard requires an implementation to provide?

Comment: *"Does the c(89) standard specify certain hardware properties that must be defined by the implementation?"* No

Comment: While the standard itself costs money, you can easily find the drafts available for free to read online. The last draft before ratification is usually identical to the then standard.

Comment: the complete list is indicated in the standard you cite, so the only identifiers that you can safely assume to appear are the ones that appear in the document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C89 specifies limits provided by `limits.h`, [see here for the freely accessible draft text](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#2.2.4.2).

As already <strike>commented by [alk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694576/alk)</strike> [answered by alk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45010660/2371524), the only one that's truly *hardware specific* is `CHAR_BIT`, the others are implementation specific.

As for `__WORDSIZE`, this isn't a standard define, and it's questionable what a *word size* should be.

You can always determine the number of bits in a type using an ingenious macro found for example [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4589384/2371524), quoting it here:

```
/* Number of bits in inttype_MAX, or in any (1<<b)-1 where 0 <= b < 3E+10 */
#define IMAX_BITS(m) ((m) /((m)%0x3fffffffL+1) /0x3fffffffL %0x3fffffffL *30 \
                  + (m)%0x3fffffffL /((m)%31+1)/31%31*5 + 4-12/((m)%31+3))
```

With this, you can determine the size in bits of an `unsigned int` like this:

```
IMAX_BITS((unsigned)-1)
```

But is this really the *word size*? On x86_64, the result will be 32, while pointers are 64 bits.

With **C99** and later, you could instead use

```
IMAX_BITS((uintptr_t)-1)
```

But be aware that `uintptr_t` is only required to be able to hold a pointer -- it *could* be larger.

Comment: " (1<<b)-1 where 0 <= b < 3E+10" is certainly amiss.  Shifting 1 by such a larger value as  3E+10 is strange.  I think you mean " (1<<b)-1 where 0 <= b < 31" or abouts.

Comment: @chux no, it really works for (hypothetical) large numbers like this. See the original answer as well as a link there to some usenet posting for explanations.

Comment: Yes I see that now.

Answer (score 4):

`CHAR_BIT` comes to my mind (see 5.2.4.2.1/1 of the C11 Standard draft).

It defines the width (number of bits) of the smallest integer that is not a bit field. On recent systems this typically is 8.

Still, whether this is necessarily to be taken as hardware property is arguable.

C tries to abstract hardware properties. That is probably a (main?) reason why it spread.

Comment: Or in the [C89 standard draft](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html) under 2.2.4.2 Numerical limits. `__WORDSIZE` is compiler internal as said here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30734004/8051589

Comment: uv'ing, still a question: what would be the argument that `CHAR_BIT` does *not* relate to a hardware property?

Comment: @FelixPalmen: I could imagine a C implementation on a 9 bit hardware using 8 bits per "byte" only. Might make sense on a 8.5 bit hardware (each even byte is 8 bit, each odd byte is 9 bit)... ;-)